# How to Display custom error code and custom error message in catch block?

Tags: apexrest

```java
@RestResource(urlMapping='/AccountThrowErrorCode/')
global class AccountError {
    @HttpPost
    global static Account doPost(){
        string jsonResponse='';
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse response = RestContext.response;
        String requestBody = System.RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
        AccWrapperError acc = (AccWrapperError)JSON.deserialize(requestBody,AccWrapperError.class);

        try{
            if(string.isBlank(acc.Name) || string.isBlank(acc.phone))
                throw new accountCodeException('Fields should not be Empty');
        }
        else{
            Account accRecord = new Account();
            accRecord.Name = acc.Name;
            accRecord.Phone = acc.Phone;
            accRecord.Rating = acc.Rating;
            insert accRecord;
            return accRecord;
        }
        catch (accountCodeException e) {
            accountCodeException aa;
            throw new accountCodeException('New error '{errorCode:201,errorMessage:+e.getMessage()});
        }
    }

    public class accountCodeException extends Exception {
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Thank you for the code, but you need to please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/381509/edit) your question to also add *exactly* (e.g., exact error text, details of unexpected behavior) how it is not working. *(From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): 'Your question should include...A specific, detailed description of the issue ("it doesn’t work" is not enough to allow the community to help).')*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using a new apex class, with two properties: `code` and `message`:

```
public class CustomExceptionResponse {
    
    private String code;
    private String message;
    
    public CustomExceptionResponse(String code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

and then when you throw your custom exception, serialize the object, something like this:

```
catch (Exception e) {
   String error = JSON.serialize(new CustomExceptionResponse('201', 'Your Custom Message Here plus: ' + e.getMessage()));
   throw new accountCodeException(error);
}
```

Hope this helps!